# Is there an attribute to set test timeout for all tests in TestClass at once?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, attributes, mstest

I have mstest `TestClass` that contains 35 tests now and that might grow. Methods tested are often recursive (so there might be bug causing infinite loop), so I want to set timeout for those tests.

Is there a way (ideally an attribute) to set same timeout for all tests at one place? `TimeoutAttribute` can only be used with methods, not classes. And I really don't like copying same `TimeoutAttribute` 35 times.

Alternatively, can I create my own `Attribute` that can be used with class and that marks every method in that class with specified attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this through the test runner configuration. (More details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx#timeoutalltests)).

> **To set the test run time-out for all tests using the tests settings file**
>
> 1. Open Solution Explorer.
> 2. In the Solution Items folder of your solution, double-click the test settings file. (The Configuration Settings dialog box appears.)
> 3. Choose Test Timeouts.
> 4. Check Abort a test run if its total execution time exceeds:
> 5. Set the test run time-out value, in hours, minutes, and seconds.
> 6. Choose Save and then choose Close.
>
> For this setting to take effect, the test settings that you edited
>   must be the active test settings. For more information, see [How to:
>   Select the Active Test Settings from Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182481.aspx).